# Raw pointers w/o unsafe

Tags: pointers, rust

To dereference a raw pointer, we must use `unsafe` code. What are the situations in which raw pointers can be used (and can be useful) in ways that don't involve using `unsafe` code at all?

Comment: What do you mean by "entirely safe context"? Do you mean it is sound? The standard library is full of raw pointers.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I guess the expression I used wasn't correct, so I edited my question.

Comment: Why would you want anything like that?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I don't have a particular problem I need to solve. I am just learning and want to have a better understanding on the matter.

Comment: You can use raw pointers as object identity when, say, traversing a graph of `Arc`s.

Comment: Pointers are meant to be... pointers to objects. If you can do things with them that don't require `unsafe`, congrats, but that's not their purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much the only thing you can do is cast the raw pointer to an usize. You can use that to do stuff like getting the index in an array from a reference into the array.

```
fn get_index_in_array(array: &[i32], item: &i32) -> usize {
    let array_ptr: *const i32 = array.as_ptr();
    let item_ptr: *const i32 = item;
    
    let distance = ((item_ptr as usize) - (array_ptr as usize)) / std::mem::size_of::<i32>();
    assert!(distance < array.len());
    distance
}

fn main() {
    let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    
    println!("{}", get_index_in_array(&arr, &arr[2]));
}
```

```
2
```